# how can I increase the performance for below code

Tags: linux, ksh

Below is my script which is having lot of performance issue

```sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh
while read i
do
  x=`echo $i |cut -d"|" -f2`
  rem=`expr $x % 62`
  echo "reminder is " $rem
  quo=`expr $x / 62`
  echo "quotiont is " $quo

  grp_rem=" "
  if [[ ${#quo} -ge 2 ]]
  then
    while [ $quo -ge 62 ]
    do
      sub_rem=`expr $quo % 62`
      quo=`expr $quo / 62`
      grp_rem=`echo $sub_rem" "$grp_rem`
    done
  fi
  echo $i"|"$quo" "$grp_rem" "$rem >> base62_while.out
done < base62_while.txt
```

Is there anyway I can increase performance with above script?

sample input:

```
1|5147634738948389685
```

sample output

```
1|5147634738948389685|6 8 16 13 46 17 20 35 9 49 43
```

Comment: It's a `ksh` script. oes an optimised alternative have to be `ksh` or would a different shell (such as `bash`) be acceptable?

Comment: no, I amo not using aix,
ksh and bash is fine

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The script I optimized seems to be quite fast, this may be a counter example of your claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be considerably faster

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
#
while IFS='|' read n x
do
    base62="$(echo "obase=62; $x" | bc | sed -re 's/ 0/ /g' -e 's/^ //')"
    printf "%d|%s|%s\n" $n "$x" "$base62"
done <base62_while.txt >>base62_while.out
```

The `base62` line uses `bc` to convert the decimal source number into a base 62 equivalent. It outputs two digit decimal pairs, from which we strip any leading zero (i.e. `02` is rewritten as `2`, but `45` is left unchanged).

Input

```
1|5147634738948389685
```

Output

```
1|5147634738948389685|6 8 16 13 46 17 20 35 9 49 43
```

Comment: I like this - especially the clever use of `bc`'s default way of handling `obase > 16`

Comment: how do I pass which for which field base62 has to be done
Suppose I have 5 fileds, base62 should I apply on 3field

Comment: Provide a proper example data file (in your question) and I can amend the code here for you. But to answer your specific enquiry, the `read n x` reads two values separated by the `|` character. You could have `read a b x c d` if you wanted, and then write them out with the `printf` at the bottom of the loop

Comment: @roaima I got this.
Actually I want to want to assign a static alpha values to the reminder, sub reminder and quo with alpha characters, I will post it here in next comment. 

and one more thing I want to replace the spaces for output. like it should be
 6816134617203594943 instead of 6 8 16 13 46 17 20 35 9 49 43

Comment: if rem=1 then rem=a;if rem=2 then rem=b;if rem=3 then rem=c

like this a-z and A-Z for quo and rem and sub_rem so that I can reduce the output length.
I am unable to add complete static values as it too long.

Comment: Your script takes in the order of 4 seconds to process 1k values, mine only 0.133 seconds. Maybe you could take a look at it :-P

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to call out to any external tools: ksh can do arithmetic. I'm also using an array to store the remainders

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
div=62
while IFS='|' read -r n x; do
    rem=$(( x % div ))
    quo=$(( x / div ))
    echo "reminder is  $rem" >&2
    echo "quotiont is  $quo" >&2

    remainders=( $rem )
    while (( quo >= div )); do
        sub_rem=$(( quo % 62 ))
        quo=$(( quo / 62 ))
        echo "reminder is  $sub_rem" >&2
        echo "quotiont is  $quo" >&2
        remainders=( $sub_rem "${remainders[@]}" )
    done
    echo "$n|$x|$quo ${remainders[*]}"

    x=$quo
    for r in "${remainders[@]}"; do
        x=$(( x * div + r ))
    done
    echo Verification: $x
done <<END
1|5147634738948389685
END
```

Comment: When I am passing file name instead of 
1|5147634738948389685
it is reading anything. How do I pass a file name in this script

Comment: change  the heredoc `<<END ... END` to a simple redirection `< filename`

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that could be done (and speed gained):

- original on 1000 numbers
  35.023 sec
- replace all the expr commands with arithmetic expansions $((x%62))
  14.473
- convert `` grp_rem=`echo $sub_rem" "$grp_rem` `` to `grp_rem="$sub_rem $grp_rem"`
  3.131
- avoid the use of cut (`set IFS='|'; set -f`; and use shell split with `set -- $1`)

  - or use `IFS='|' read a x <<<"$i"` (though `<<<` creates a temp file)
  - and as one read is already being used, replace that read.
    0.454
- reduce to only one loop (remove the if) and remove trailing space at the end
  0.207
- Make the loop tighter Join both `$((...))`
  0.113
  ---- shell: a change of ~300 times faster than 35.023 seconds.
  ++++ This is probably the best that can be done with a shell script.
- change to awk
  0.123
  ---- awk: a total change of ~280 times faster

Resulting script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
while IFS='|' read a b             # read both values split on '|'
do
    x=$b                           # set value of x (quotient)
    grp_rem=""                     # clear value of group
    while (( rem=x%62 , x/=62 ))   # do both math expressions.
    do
        grp_rem="$rem $grp_rem"    # concatenate resulting values
    done
    grp_rem=${grp_rem%?}           # remove one character (an space)
    echo "$a|$b|$rem $grp_rem" 
done  < base62_while.txt  >> base62_while.out
```

An awk script equivalent. I don't know if this is the faster awk script possible, but works fine. Faster than the shell for more than 10k lines.
**Note:** This is using GNU awk with the option of `-M` (arbitrary precision) which is a must to process numbers in the order of 19 digits that you presented. It could process even longer numbers, I did not check how long, but I am pretty sure that the limit is pretty high. :-) Note that awk must have been compiled with that option included (check with `awk 'BEGIN{ print( PROCINFO["gmp_version"], PROCINFO["prec_max"]) }'`)

```
awk -MF'|' '{ x=$2; grp_rem="";
              while(x>0){
                          rem=x%62;
                          x=int(x/62);
                          grp_rem=rem" "grp_rem
                        }
              printf("%-22s|%s\n",$0,grp_rem)
            }
           ' <base62_while.txt >>base62_while.out
```

Comment: On a 100000 line file, I find that that gawk solution is still 3  times as fast even though it supports arbitrary precision. You can make the ksh one faster by taking the output redirection out of the loop.

Comment: This answer already has this *Faster than the shell for more than 10k lines.* So, yes, that is known. But what is faster for a few values? [Please answer this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463483/what-is-the-fastest-solution-for-a-few-values-from-the-shell) @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 2):

After playing for a bit with the [Math::Base::Convert](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Base::Convert)  perl module I came up with

```
perl -F'\|' -MMath::Base::Convert -lne '
  BEGIN{
    $bc = new Math::Base::Convert(dec,b62); 
    # create a mapping from internal symbol set to desired decimal representation
    $syms = $bc->b62; 
    @h{@$syms} = (0..61);
  } 
  print join "|", @F[0..1], (join " ", map $h{$_}, split //, $bc->cnv($F[1]))
' base62_while.txt
```

There may be faster perl alternatives as discussed here [Base conversion](http://blogs.perl.org/users/dana_jacobsen/2016/08/base-conversion.html) although I'm not sure if they have the same flexibility to manipulate the output mapping.

Answer (score 2):

With `dc`:

```
sed 's/.*|\(.*\)/[&|]P\1p/;1s/^/62o/' base62_while.txt | dc > base62_while.out
```

Or `bc` (note that historical implementations of `bc` are actually wrappers around `dc`):

```
sed 's/.*|\(.*\)/"&|";\1/;1s/^/obase=62;/' base62_while.txt | bc > base62_while.out
```

Note that `dc` and `bc` wrap long lines of output. With the GNU implementations, you can set the `DC_LINE_LENGTH` and `BC_LINE_LENGTH` environment variables to 0 to avoid it.

```
$ echo '1|167883826163764944817996215305490271305728' | sed 's/.*|\(.*\)/[&|]P\1p/;1s/^/62o/' | dc
1|167883826163764944817996215305490271305728| 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00\
 00
$ echo '1|167883826163764944817996215305490271305728' | sed 's/.*|\(.*\)/[&|]P\1p/;1s/^/62o/' | DC_LINE_LENGTH=0 dc
1|167883826163764944817996215305490271305728| 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some optimizations.

Change

```
grp_rem=`echo $sub_rem" "$grp_rem`
```

to

```
grp_rem="$sub_rem $grp_rem"
```

Change

```
x=`echo $i |cut -d"|" -f2`
```

to

```
x="${i#*|}"
```

You probably also want to change

```
if [[ ${#quo} -ge 2 ]]
```

to

```
if [[ ${quo} -ge 62 ]]
```

Reducing the number of subshells a little will help. If you want more speed, use a language like C.

Comment: how do I  select field 2 from x="${i#*|}"

Comment: It will strip everything at the front of the value the matches the pattern `*|`, in other words everything up to and including the `|`-

Answer (score 1):

The shell is slow: use a different language. If we compare the original KSH script (modified to used stdin and stdout), something very [similar to steeldriver's Perl code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463101/128228) (a script instead of a one-liner that shows similar speeds to glenn jackman's native KSH version), and a LISP implementation with 10,000 lines of input on a Centos 7 test system:

```
base62.ksh  93.29s user 143.48s system 109% cpu 3:36.73 total
base62.perl  1.32s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 1.326 total
base62.sbcl  0.22s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 0.243 total
```

Obviously the original code quickly becomes impractical as the input lines increase, as will scripting languages compared to LISP with significant amounts of input. The `base62.sbcl` time is from a tail call recursive implementation:

```
#|
eval 'exec sbcl --script "$0" ${1+"$@"}'
|#
(defun divvy-r (n b l)
  (if (< n b) (cons (truncate n) l)
    (let ((rem (truncate (mod n b))) (quo (/ n b)))
      (divvy-r quo b (cons rem l)))))
(defun divvy (n b)
  (let ((rem (mod n b)) (quo (/ n b)))
    (if (< quo 2)
      (list (truncate quo) (truncate rem))
      (divvy-r n b nil))))
(loop for line = (read-line *standard-input* nil) while line do
      (let ((n (parse-integer (subseq line (1+ (position #\| line))))))
        (let ((out (divvy n 62)))
          (format t "~a|~{~a~^ ~}~&" line out))))
```

Reading "Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation" and doing all the exercises therein is how I learned this. Slightly faster (and ever so succinct) is a `do*` implementation based on glenn jackman's KSH code:

```
#|
eval 'exec sbcl --script "$0" ${1+"$@"}'
|#
(defun remainders (n base)
  (do* ((rem (mod n base) (mod quo base))
        (quo (/ n base) (/ quo base))
        (out (cons (truncate rem) nil) (cons (truncate rem) out)))
    ((< quo base) (cons (truncate quo) out))))
(loop for line = (read-line *standard-input* nil) while line do
      (let ((n (parse-integer (subseq line (1+ (position #\| line))))))
        (format t "~a|~{~a~^ ~}~&" line (remainders n 62))))
```

Comment: It's ironic that that script actually needs a shell to run. So, the shell is not slow as long as you're using it the right way: as a command line interpreter to run the right command for the task (as opposed to dozens or invocations of ill fitted tools for each line of the input in the OP's attempt).

Comment: SBCL can compile the script to a ~39 megabyte binary which shaves ~0.01 seconds off the execution time avoiding the shell exec. Otherwise, LISP implementations are often an awkward fit for the unix shell environment...